# login with facebook returning not a valid app id

Tags: facebook, flask, oauth, flask-dance

i'm using flask, and this is the code on the back end, copied from a source listed on flask-dance documentation:

```
app.config["FACEBOOK_OAUTH_CLIENT_ID"] = os.environ.get("xxxxxxx")
app.config["FACEBOOK_OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET"] = os.environ.get("yyyyyy")
facebook_bp = make_facebook_blueprint()
app.register_blueprint(facebook_bp, url_prefix="/login")

@app.route("/")
def index():
    if not facebook.authorized:
        return redirect(url_for("facebook.login"))
    resp = facebook.get("/me")
    assert resp.ok, resp.text
    return "You are {name} on Facebook".format(name=resp.json()["name"])
```

on the front end, i have this, provided by facebook itself:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = 
        function()
        {
            FB.init
            (
                {
                    //Generate through Facebook developer page
                    appId:"xxxxxxx",
                    cookie: true,
                    xfbml: true,
                    version: "v4.0"
                }
            );
            getLoginStatus();
        }
    function getLoginStatus()
    {

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(res){
        if( res.status == "connected" ){
            FB.api('/me', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,picture.width(150).height(150)'}, function(fbUser) {
                // console.log(fbUser.name);
                var id = fbUser.id;
                var name = fbUser.name;
                date = new Date().toLocaleString();
                var my_data = {name:name,id:id,date:date,language:language};
                $.ajax({url: "/fb",data: my_data,type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    console.log('error in fb');
                }})

            });
        }
    });
    }
    function checkLoginState()
    {
        getLoginStatus();
    }
    (
        function (d, s, id)
        {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)){return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

        }
    )(document, "script", "facebook-jssdk");
```

i'm 100% sure both the app id and app secret are correct (just copied and pasted it). i checked another stackoverflow topic on this issue and people were suggesting the OP to make sure he wasn't on sandbox mode. i never even heard of it, but i did try switching to debug=False.

Comment: What is the exact error message, and at which point does it appear? Have you correctly configured the settings for the website platform and client-side login?

Comment: the error message comes from facebook. it's this not valid ID message. it appears when i try to access the website. the settings are these: client oauth login: yes; weboauth login: yes ; enforce https: yes; force web oauth reauthentication: yes; embedded browser oauth login: yes; use strict mode for redirect uris: yes; login from devices: yes; native or desktop app? yes; is app secret embedded in the client? no @04FS